Nextjs 14 and mongoDB TypeError: res.status is not a function on GET request
working on a nextjs project using mongodb. Using app router, trying to test api calls using the following code, weirdly enough I get a response from the db
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse, NextApiHandler } from "next";
import User from "../../model/User";
import clientPromise from "../../lib/mongodb";

// Handle GET method
export const GET: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
  await clientPromise;
  const allUsers = await User.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.toString() });
    });
};


TypeError: res.status is not a function`

I have tried to console log it but the error is never cleared. DB is happy but just keep getting 500 server error
I have tried doing this slightly different as below
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  await clientPromise;
  const allUsers = await User.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.toString() });
    });
}


What is that backslash arrow function syntax? Is it possible it's (somehow) erasing the surrounding context? Also, I believe you'll need to return the value returned by the promise handlers in order for the response to be propagated to the client.

just something weird that stack overflow added when  I changed the view when creating the question thanks for flagging that

You appear to be using Next.js route handlers which need to return a response. They are not passed the response like API routes. Don't confuse the two

Does this answer your question? From pages to app (NextJS): rest.status is not a function

I think you're mixing the old way (Pages Router) and the new way (App Router).
It's possible to use both forms in the same Next.js project versions 13 and 14, but not in the same place.
In your project, you can have APIs in:

Page Router: /pages/api/ or src/pages/api/
App Router: /app/api or src/app/api/

Here are two examples of APIs in both directories:
File: /src/pages/api/users/index.ts or /src/pages/api/users.ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const allUsers = {
        users: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'John Doe',
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'foo bar',
            },
        ],
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ allUsers })
}

File: /src/app/api/users/route.ts (the name route is mandatory and is not part of the URL to call)
export async function GET() {
    const allUsers = {
        users: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'john Doe',
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Foo Bar',
            },
        ],
    }

    return Response.json({ allUsers })
}

see: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers

Absolute legend. the second option was my file structure. I miss understood the documentation, hugely appreciated
